# Move Joomla website from live server to localhost - Error 500

Tags: apache, joomla

I have to put a Joomla website from live server to localhost, I tried this steps:

1. made a site backup via FTP;
2. made a database backup and restored it on local mysql;
3. created the database user and gave him all grants for db;
4. modified `configuration.php` setting `$user`, `$db` as on the server, `$tmp_path` and `$log_path` that point to the local directory;
5. set permissions on local directory to 777;
6. uncommented Apache module `mod_rewrite.so` in httpd.conf;
7. renamed `php.ini` in the site local root in `php.ini.bak`;
8. renamed `.htaccess` in `htaccess.txt`;
9. I tried to use an `.htaccess` file from a new Joomla installation

and I still have Error 500.

My localhost root is /Users/'username'/Sites/'my_website'.
If it can be useful, I moved a more basic Joomla website in localhost than what I have to move, and it worked on my system.

OS X 10.10.2
Apache 2.4.9
MySQL 5.6.24
PHP 5.5.14
Joomla 3.4.5 Stable

Comment: I think you actually need to install joomla on your local server and then move your whole made website to it.

Comment: No that's not necessary. Can you get a regular html file to render?

Comment: Yes, Apache is up, i moved another Joomla website in localhost and it worked

Comment: SOLVED: the problem was related to SSL certificate and mod_rewrite module, I followed these steps: https://www.dev-metal.com/enable-mod_rewrite-ubuntu-14-04-lts/ , instead of modifying 000-default.conf I changed 000-default-ssl.conf